# unable to get date from html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

unable to get date from a tag within tags. Tried with regression but not working, how to get the following output with/without regression.

Required output:

```
Saturday, November 25, 2017
```

html code:

```
<div class="main-content">
<div class="col_7 post-info">strong text
<ul class="no-bullet">
<li><strong>Date:</strong> Saturday, November 25, 2017</li>
<li><strong>Category:</strong> bicycles</li>
<li><strong>Region:</strong> Je (
<new_region>
street
</new_region>
)</li>
<li><strong>Posting ID:</strong> 37021705</li>

<li><button class="btn big primary posting-phone"><span class="icon-phone"></span> <a href="tel:0503748197">0503748197</a></button></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

python code:

```
            soup=BeautifulSoup(pages,'lxml').find('div','main-content') 
            #soup=BeautifulSoup(pages,'lxml').find('div','col_7 post-info')     
            ulobj=soup.find('ul','no-bullet')
            date=ulobj.findAll(re.compile('\d+\s[a-z]+,\s\d{4}'))
            print(date)
```

wrong output:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and state exactly what output you are expecting to get.

Comment: I stated that i'm trying to get date, anyhow as per your advise clearly mentioned the required output. hope you could suggest something? thanks

Comment: I asked, because your regexp doesn't look like it's trying to match anything like what is in the example html. Anyway, something like this should work: `date=ulobj.find_all(string=re.compile(r'\b\w+[,\s]+\w+\s+\d{1,2}[,\s]+\d{4}\b'))`.

Comment: \thanks for the suggestion bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the code i came up with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(pages,'html.parser').find('div','main-content') 

ulobj = soup.find('ul','no-bullet')
date = ulobj.find("li").text;
print(date)
```

which gives the output:

```
Date: Saturday, November 25, 2017
```

and to get the output you require just

```
 >>> print(date[6:])
 Saturday, November 25, 2017
```

but it only works because its the first li in the html code

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: i think the problem with regex, better if you could help without regex.. thanks

Comment: So fixed the problem by using find to find the first li and remove tags. Note: the html.parser is just a builtin no difference there.